# RESTDataSource equivalent for mutations

Tags: rest, apollo-server

I built a GraphQL server using `RESTDataSource` to make requests to our API to handle queries.  Is there an equivalent to handle mutations via POSTs to a REST API?  Or is there an easy way to implement this myself?

Comment: `RESTDataSource` [already supports](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/features/data-sources/#http-methods) POST methods (and PUT, PATCH and DELETE). You can call your DataSource's methods inside any field resolver. So it's a bit unclear what you're asking here. Can you please provide additional details?

Comment: I just needed to RTFM.  Thanks for the link.  The "data source" part threw me off; I didn't realize it was bi-directional.